# Как передать данные из селекта VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть форма:

```
<div class="md-layout">
    <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100 md-small-100">
        <md-field>
            <label>Формат печати</label>
            <md-select v-model="templates">
                <md-option v-for="format in templates" :key="format">{{ format }}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-field>
    </div>
</div>
<md-button class="md-raised" @click="testPrint()">Тестовая печать</md-button>
```

Как забрать с селекта выбранное значение?

Из темплейтов приходит массив со стрингами. они идут в селект. Выбранную стрингу нужно передать в testPrint()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что бы получить выбранное значение из `select` нужно, в `v-model` указать переменную в `data` с которой это значение будет связано. Например `selected`.

```html
<div class="md-layout">
    <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100 md-small-100">
        <md-field>
            <label>Формат печати</label>
            <md-select v-model="selected">
                <md-option v-for="format in templates"  :value="format" :key="format">{{ format }}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-field>
    </div>
</div>
<md-button class="md-raised" @click="testPrint()">Тестовая печать</md-button>
```

Затем это значение можно будет получить в любом методе, хуке, вычисляемом свойстве и т.д. через `this`.

```js
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return {
           selected: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
       testPrint(){
          alert(this.selected);
       }
    }
</script>
```

Если его нужно вывести в `template`, то `this` не нужно использовать.

```html
<template>
   <!-- вывод selected в шаблоне -->
   {{selected}}
   <div class="md-layout">
    <div class="md-layout-item md-size-100 md-small-100">
        <md-field>
            <label>Формат печати</label>
            <md-select v-model="selected">
                <md-option v-for="format in templates"  :value="format" :key="format">{{ format }}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-field>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Это всё должно сработать при условии, что внутри компонента md-select правильно прокинута v-model.

Comment: А что значит "Правильно прокинута?" В селектед уходит false, хотя в селекте стринги

Comment: @voidsMark, я имею ввиду что внутри компонента md-select правильно прописаны emits, props и т.д, что бы v-model на пользовательском компоненте правильно работала. 
Если это, какой то компонент из сторонней библиотеки компонентов, то скорее всего всё будет Ок. 
Если вы сами сделали этот компонент и он бы не работал, так как я описывал в своём ответе, то скорее проблема в компоненте. 
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html

Comment: @voidsMark , возможно в selected уходи false, потому что на md-option, нужно добавить value и в него записывать вашу итерацию format. 

Должно быть что то вроде этого 
<md-option v-for="format in templates" :value="format" :key="format">{{ format }}</md-option>

Comment: @voidsMark, нашёл эту библиотеку которую вы используете,  на сайте документации этот в  md-option везде есть value. В ответе сейчас исправлю как оно должно быть